# Setting alias in Windows PowerShell

Tags: windows-7, powershell, alias

In PowerShell, I type:

<kbd>PS C:> sal cdp "cd 'C:\Users\ec\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects'"</kbd>

I get no error from this, and

<kbd>PS C:> gal cdp</kbd>

shows definition as: cd 'C:\Users\ec\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects'

But, when I try to use cdp, I get this:

> Cannot resolve alias 'cdp' because it refers to term 'cd 'C:\Users\ec\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects'', which is not recognized as a cmdlet, function, operable program, or script file. Verify the term and try again.
>   At line:1 char:4
>   + cdp <<<<
>    + CatergoryInfo   : ObjectNotFound (dsp:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>    + FullyQualifiedErrorId   : AliasNotResolvedException

I am guessing that this is trivially easy. So I apologize in advance if that is the case. I have googled and googled and have also read through Windows PowerShell Cookbook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my understanding, aliases in piowershell do not behave like they do in unix/linux type shells. An alias is merely a shorthand way of typing a much longer command. For the functionality that you are looking for, it may be easier to eaither define a function:

> function cdp { Set-Location 'C:\Users\ec\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects' }

Then you can execute cdp on the line to get to the desired location. Or you can create a variable for the location and then cd to that variable name:

```
$cdp = 'C:\Users\ec\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects'
cd $cdp
```

Those are the two easiest solutions to what it appears you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I am trying to replicate *nix shell scripting behavior. Both of your suggestions worked for me - so I will see if I can get them to persist in some easily re-useable form.

Comment: Even though you haven't opened a question regarding the persistence issue, at the powershell prompt execute `get-help about_profile` that'll help you out with the persistence issue

Comment: Thanks. At the risk of running amok of etiquette, I settled on using profile.ps1 in Documents/WindowsPowerShell/ as the easiest path. That works well for my immediate needs - much like .profile on other systems.

Comment: Well then I am an amok runner as well. Pretty much all my shell customizations go into my AllUsersAllHosts profile as well.